# How to write action on a alert box ok button in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to .net application development. In my project i created one form ,when i click on submit button,those values inserted  into data base.If it is successfully inserted,then my form navigated to another form using response.redirect("*home.aspx*").

But in this when is click on submit button,values are inserted into database,but with out showing the alert message ,my page navigated to home.aspx page.

But my requirement is,it should have to show the alert message,after click on alert box OK button then it is navigate to another page.

Any help appreciated

```
public static void ShowAlertMessage(string error)
{
    Page page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
    if (page != null)
    {
        error = error.Replace("'", "");
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, page.GetType(), "err_msg", "alert('" + error + "');", true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show your current code?

Comment: public static void ShowAlertMessage(string error)
        {
            Page page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
            if (page != null)
            {
                error = error.Replace("'", "");
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, page.GetType(), "err_msg", "alert('" + error + "');", true);
              
            }
        }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, page.GetType(), "err_msg", "alert('" + error + "');window.location='pagename.aspx';", true);
```

you will have to redirect using `window.loacation` in you javascript function only.Remove `Response.Redirect()`.

Response.redirect is server side code and it does not wait to execute client side code. if we will write both statement on client side then it will work fine.