# how to close current webform after display messagebox

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I use the code below to open a message box:

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Messagebox", "alert('Record Updated successfully.Note: This tab is now getting close');", true);

        }
```

How to close the current page after a click on the OK button of this message box?

Comment: iam using webform not window forms..

Comment: @GravCude, unfortunately they said web forms not win forms so .aspx and that doesn't work

Comment: I mean current browser tab...

Comment: Maybe a helpful link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16248895/how-to-write-action-on-a-alert-box-ok-button-in-c

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I should've elaborated. [`window.close()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close) is a **Javascript** function which closes the current window.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically close aspx page from code behind](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375406/programmatically-close-aspx-page-from-code-behind)

Answer (score 0):

in web forms you can't close the page, what you will have to do is redirect the page to a different page, and if you add the redirect after the alert it should happen when the alert closes

if you don't know how to redirect a page then this may help
[aspx page to redirect to a new page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093081/aspx-page-to-redirect-to-a-new-page)
however webforms is something i'm still learning myself

Answer (score 0):

Open the current page as popup using window.open() then write a Javascript function in the page such as

```
<script>
function confirmAndClose()
{
    var conf = confirm("Confirm to close");
    if (conf == true) {
          window.close();
                      } 
}
</script>
```

then change you server side code to

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, "script","confirmAndClose()");
```

Comment: throwing error No overload for method 'RegisterClientScriptBlock' takes 3 arguments

Comment: Sorry, it should be   Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "JSScript", "confirmAndClose()")

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

string message = "alert('Your Approval Has Been Saved Success');self.close();";
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock((sender as Control), this.GetType(), "alert", message, true);